# How can we create a zero account in an anchor program?

Tags: anchor

I am trying to creating a zero copy account but i am not aware of how i can do that and I have some questions regarding do we have to set the size of the zero copy account or it works differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link to the zero copy sample in Anchor's Github repo: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/tree/master/tests/zero-copy

Check that out first.

The breakdown is that you use an `#[account(zero_copy)]` attribute for the data structure instead of the usual `#[account]`, use an `AccountLoader` instead of an `Account` in the validator, and load the account in the instruction using `let <account_name> = ctx.accounts.<account_name>.load_init()?`.

Regarding the space, that depends on you. Using `#[account(init)]` to create the account in the validator will demand that you input the space argument and payer argument. If you want to get around that then just use `#[account(zero)]` instead.